# Use CHARINDEX rather than IN clause to speed up SSRS report filters

Tags: reporting-services

In some cases, we are using IN clause in our filters of SSRS reports. A lots of them are causing issues with the performance by using hundreds of items inside of IN clauses.
such as:

```
WHERE TableA.School IN (@School)
```

sometimes, the multi-value parameters are really tricky to handle, you might need to do =Join(Mypara.Value,",") in the RDL and write a SQL function to convert them into a set of SQL data to be able to feed the SQL SP. (especially some older version of SSRS).

FYI: function to use to break a comma deliminator string into record set:

```
CREATE function [dbo].[fnSpark_BreakUpList] (
    @List VARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS @csvlist TABLE (Item VARCHAR(MAX))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Item VARCHAR(MAX)


    -- Loop through each item in the comma delimited list
    WHILE (LEN(@List) > 0)
    BEGIN
        IF CHARINDEX(',',@list) > 0
        BEGIN
            SET @Item = SUBSTRING(@List,1,(CHARINDEX(',', @List)-1))
            SET @List = SUBSTRING(@List,(CHARINDEX(',', @List) + DATALENGTH(',')),DATALENGTH(@List))
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @Item = @List
            SET @List = NULL
        END

        -- Insert each  item into the csvlist table
        INSERT into @csvlist (Item) VALUES (@Item)
    END
    RETURN
END
GO
```

I will post answers shortly to show how to increase the performance by using CHARINDEX. (So you dont have to anything like above....)

Comment: `WHERE TableA.School IN (@School)` doesn't work correctly anyway.

Comment: it does, sometimes you have to use JOIN with your parameter set n RDL and reconstruct them into a record set in SQL i to make the IN clause working. (Depends on the version of SSRS you are using, you might/might  not even have to make work around for the multiple value parameters in some cases)

Comment: i will post the function of breaking up the long string version of record into a SQL record set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not actually want to retrieve the item from the LONG delimited string, but to only filtering it, CHARINDEX is a better way to go for.

Instead of using IN Clause, you could just use:

```
WHERE CHARINDEX(','+TableA.School+',',','​+@School+',') > 0
```

NOTE:
1. I pad an extra comma at the end of target string 'TableA.School'  to avoid the satuation that if a big string contains a sub string same as the filtering item.
(Such as we have a school called 'AB' and another 'ABC' that we dont want the 'ABC' to be picked up when we are targeting for 'AB'.... )

2. I pad an extra comma at the end of resources string​ '@School' to ensure that the single item / the last item (they will end without a comma) to be picked up when we are targeting them.
3. I pad an extra comma at the begining of target string 'TableA.School'  to avoid the satuation that if a big string contains a sub string same as the filtering item.
   (Such as we have a school called 'AB' and another 'CAB' that we dont want the 'CAB' to be picked up when we are targeting for 'AB'.... )

Example:

I am using:

```
WHERE
CHARINDEX(','+CAST(DENTIST4.wStudentYear AS VARCHAR(10))+',',','+@StudentYear+',') > 0
```

TO replace:

```
WHERE
DENTIST4.wStudentYear IN (@StudentYear)
```

for one of the report i was doing, which makes 4000+ pages rendering improved from about 10 mins into under a min for a large database (11 G).

IMPORTANT NOTES:
Please make sure the filter report parameters you are passing into the dataset uses JOIN clause.

```
=Join(Parameters!MyParameter.Value,",")​
```

Hope this helps....

IMPORTANT: This approach ONLY improves performance if the filter has large set of items, for any filters with small set of items IN clause will do better jobs.